# Communication between Tasks using asyncio and MicroPython

Tags: architecture, python-asyncio, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico

This is my first MicroPython project, using a Raspberry Pi Pico W.

I'm trying to make a timer for races, having a TOF laser senor at the finish line, a LCD display, and a webserver on the WiFi.

Coming from NodeJS I was initially thinking a RaceTimer coroutine, controlling the start button and the laser sensor. And it would fire an event when the clock started, and when the laser detected a significant change in the measured distance.  (A firing an event is fine JavaScript thing to do.)

I now realize that an *asyncio event* is quite different from a *JavaScript event*. I don't want to block the coroutines controlling the LCD display, nor the webserver, waiting for an *asyncio event* or *queue*.

So, what is the MicroPython/asyncio way to broadcast when someone has crossed the finish line with a data value for the time spent on the lap?

An ansyncio event carries no data values, and a queue has only one recipient, right?

How do I architecture this the roight way? Working *with* the tools in asyncio and micropython, and not being stuck in a JavaScript way of solving this?